# How to get the sum of numbers in a vector with two string variables?

Tags: c++

How would I get the total of the numbers in the vector of MAXARR?
The code below only sort the vector but I want to know how to the sum of the left part of each array by getting the sum. But I have no clue where to even begin.

This is the code to used to sort vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class NameAndNumber
{
public:
    std::string number;
    std::string name;
    NameAndNumber();
    NameAndNumber(std::string nam, std::string num);
    void show();
};
#define MAXARR 10
NameAndNumber arr[MAXARR] = { {"2100","Fred"},
{"2300","Jane"}, {"2112","Tony"},{"230","Owen"}, {"21010","Jamison"},
        {"2310","Akmed"}, {"1112","OneOneOneTwo"},
        {"1301","Sung"}, {"1013","Luke Skywalker"},{"20010","Kevin Jamison"}
}; // THANk YOU FOR STAnDard ALLOCATORS 
NameAndNumber::NameAndNumber(string num, string nam)
{
    name = nam;
    number = num;
}
NameAndNumber::NameAndNumber() // default constructor
{
    name = "";
    number = "";
}
void NameAndNumber::show()
{
    cout << setw(7) << number << " " << setw(20) << name << " ";
}
int main1()
{
    std::cout << "------------------------------------ \n";
    NameAndNumber temp;
    int sum = 0;
   

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXARR; i++)
    {

        for (int k = 1; k < MAXARR; k++)
        {

            if (stoi(arr[k].number) < stoi(arr[k - 1].number))
            {
                temp = arr[k];
                arr[k] = arr[k - 1];
                arr[k - 1] = temp;
                

            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXARR; i++)
    {
        arr[i].show();
        cout << " - [" << i << "]\n";

        
    }
    std::cout << "------------------------------------ \n";


    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    main1();


return 0;
}
```

The vector has both variables in the array as strings, so I will also need help on how to change them into integers.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Comment: If the issue is about totaling up the numbers, why are you showing us sorting code?  Sorting has nothing to do with totaling up the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would I get the total of the numbers in the vector of MAXARR?

Use [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) to add up the values.

Use [std::stoi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to convert the string version of the number to an integer.

```
#include <numeric>
//...
int32_t total = std::accumulate(arr, arr + MAXARR, 0L, 
                               [&](int32_t total, NameAndNumber& n) 
                               { return total + std::stoi(n.number); });
```

[Full Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/067125adf415c86a).

Comment: Ehm, let me mention `std::from_chars`